# Google form email confirmation script throws undefined error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google form that users input sports they are signing up for.  They input their email, address, name, etc..  I then have a column added in the spreadsheet for **Total** which is an **arrayformula** which calculates based on their answers the total they owe.  The spreadsheet with the form upon user submit works great.

However in Script Manager i have a function that is triggered on onFormSubmit (see below).  When a user fills out and submits a form, the "confirmation" email is sent, and all fields are as they should be EXCEPT the Total comes up as **undefined** -- this is the arrayformula column.  why?  are we not able to send those fields?  I really need the email to tell the user how much they owe.  **How do I reference that Total column for the row that was just submitted by the user?**

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var toAddress = e.values[1];
  var LastName = e.values[2];
  var Street = e.values[3];
  var City = e.values[4];
  var Zip = e.values[5];
  var Phone = e.values[6];
  var Student1 = e.values[7];
  var GradeS1 = e.values[8];
  var BdayS1 = e.values[9];
  var GenderS1 = e.values[10];
  var SportS1 = e.values[11];
  var Student2 = e.values[12];
  var GradeS2 = e.values[13];
  var BdayS2 = e.values[14];
  var GenderS2 = e.values[15];
  var SportS2 = e.values[16];
  var Student3 = e.values[17];
  var GradeS3 = e.values[18];
  var BdayS3 = e.values[19];
  var GenderS3 = e.values[20];
  var SportS3 = e.values[21];
  var Student4 = e.values[22];
  var GradeS4 = e.values[23];
  var BdayS4 = e.values[24];
  var GenderS4 = e.values[25];
  var SportS4 = e.values[26]; 
  var Total = e.values[30];

  var subject = "Registration"; 

  var htmlBody = "The Registration details you entered were as follows:" +
      "<br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date/Time Submitted:  &nbsp;" + timestamp +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Family:  &nbsp;" + LastName +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Address:  &nbsp;" + Street + ", &nbsp;" + City + ", &nbsp;" + Zip + 
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone:  &nbsp;" + Phone +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student 1:  &nbsp;" + Student1 + ", &nbsp;" + GradeS1 + ", &nbsp;" + BdayS1 + ", &nbsp;" + GenderS1 + ", &nbsp;" + SportS1 +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student 2:  &nbsp;" + Student2 + ", &nbsp;" + GradeS2 + ", &nbsp;" + BdayS2 + ", &nbsp;" + GenderS2 + ", &nbsp;" + SportS2 +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student 3:  &nbsp;" + Student3 + ", &nbsp;" + GradeS3 + ", &nbsp;" + BdayS3 + ", &nbsp;" + GenderS3 + ", &nbsp;" + SportS3 +
      "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student 4:  &nbsp;" + Student4 + ", &nbsp;" + GradeS4 + ", &nbsp;" + BdayS4 + ", &nbsp;" + GenderS4 + ", &nbsp;" + SportS4 +
      "<br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TOTAL DUE:  &nbsp;<b>$" + Total + 
        "</b><br/><br/>Please send your payment, <b>checks payable to Our Company </B> , to:  &nbsp;<font color=\"red\"><b>Person Name</font></b>" +
      "<br/><br/>Your registration will not be activated until payment is received.  Thank you so much!" +
      "<br/><br/>From Our Company";

  var optAdvancedArgs = {name: "Our Company", htmlBody: htmlBody};

  MailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, subject, "Message Body", optAdvancedArgs);

}
```

THANK YOU, please if you can help!

Comment: Could you share a copy of you spreadsheet and form so that I can suggest a working code without having to rewrite the whole thing for my tests?  Just don't leave personal data in it...  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your array code.  I'm guessing the array has a length of less than 30(29) perhaps.  That or the array is somehow not inserting data correctly.  I also like to throw a .toString() when declaring a value;

Comment: Here is the code in the array:

    =ArrayFormula(AK2:AK+AQ2:AQ+AW2:AW+BC2:BC)

i have tried to add the .toString -- i have scoured the internet for an answer.  unless i was adding it wrong it didnt work

Comment: ****HOWEVER!  I am not sure even how to add a comment to this forum, so I'm not feeling very confident!  This is difficult... you cant hit 'enter'?

Comment: (see if this works)

Here is the code in the array: 

`=ArrayFormula(AK2:AK+AQ2:AQ+AW2:AW+BC2:BC)`

 i have tried to add the .toString -- i have scoured the internet for an answer. unless i was adding it wrong it didnt work

Comment: and also Kevrone... when you say the array has a length less than 30, I was under the impression 30 was in reference to the column?  On the spreadsheet it is column AE, but it appeared to me that you were supposed to put the number instead... and the standard "timeframe" was column 0   is that right?

Comment: So, I also just discovered `Logger.log(e.values)` and it shows all my e.values, which do only go up to 29.  columns 30-40 are where my calculations/arrayformulas are.  **So I guess the ultimate question is... can you tack on those calculated field in a script onformsubmit? **

Comment: Yes you should extend arrayformula out a bit it should pick up the values so long as they have a value not the "=sum()" stuff.   So your array will just be a bit bigger.

Comment: BTW the reason your array was 29 not 30 is because they always start arrays at 0 so 0-29 is actually 30 rows of data.

Comment: Kev, what do you mean "extend arrayformula out a bit"?  are you saying I can pass that column onformsubmit?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your question, the TOTAL variable is not defined in the form but in the spreadsheet instead... so it is normal that it doesn't correspond to any `e.parameter` linked to / coming along with the form. (e.values[x] are referenced to the form question index, not the spreadsheet columns even if in practice these  are the same reference numbers)

You should try to get this value where it is, ie in the spreadsheet !

Since I don't know your spreadsheet layout I'm not able to tell you where it is but you should  be able to do it easily.

The other possible option is to process the data in the script itself by doing the same operation you do in the spreadsheet cell at script level... if it is just adding variables values it shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: I did mess around with putting it in the script itself.  I'm just struggling with the correct usage.  Give me sql, i'm ok, java not so much.  Could you tell me how to write:

let's say variable Field1 contains answers like "baseball, track" and variable Field2 contains answers like 7

how do you say IF Field1 contains baseball OR track and Field2 contains either "7,8,9,10", then AnswerB, else AnswerC?

I would be grateful forever!  I have messed around with this so much, my head hurts :)  Thank you!!